# Unable to get Linkedin to return data from socialActions v2 endpoints

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am using the Linkedin API OAuth 2.0 API and trying to perform a 'like' to a post or a comment using the new version 2 of the Linkedin API using the Postman client.

I have added the following permissions to the scope
`r_liteprofile r_emailaddress rw_organization_admin w_organization_social r_organization_social w_member_social w_organization_social r_organization_social`

And added the relevant callback, Auth & Access Token URLs to the postman request along with the Client ID and Client Secret ID.

When I perform a request to the `\me` v2 endpoint it returns relevant data.

When I perform the following GET request it gives me an not enough permissions error (even though it has been recently been accepted to the Marketing API for Linkedin)

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/urn%3Ali%3Aorganisation%3A24799518/comments`

I would expect to get data - but get a 403 status code and the error message below -
`Not enough permissions to access: GET /socialActions/urn%3Ali%3Aorganisation%3A24799518/comments"`

The cURL request looks as follows :

```
curl -X GET \https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/urn%3Ali%3Aorganisation%3A24799518/comments \   
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {MY BEARER TOKEN HERE}' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Postman-Token: 59c239c2-d1c7-48ee-9e5f-a894afde95dc' \
-H 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

-- update --
I have manually tried this using cURL also with the `X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0` header and have the same issue. I am ultimately trying to use the API to like posts/comments etc..

Comment: Can you show some code where you have fetched this API? And What language are you using?

Comment: did you re-requested access token after adding new permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

Social Action Api is not applicable for organization|Page

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/{shareUrn|ugcPostUrn|commentUrn}/comments
```

It is applicable for share|ugcPost|Comment

Use the following request to fetch the shares and use the share Id in the above request to get the comments for the post

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?owners=urn:li:organization:24799518&q=owners&count=100
```